# How to Change the Bulb on an Omega Enlarger?

Tags: film, printing, darkroom

Alright, recently bought an Omega C700 enlarger, and when I turn it on, nothing happens - so I'm assuming the bulb's dead. The issue is, I have no idea how to change it. It looks like you unscrew the assembly at the top, but it doesn't seem to want to come off. I can't seem to find a manual online either, or any information on this, besides [this forum](https://www.photography-forums.com/threads/omega-c700-enlarger-help.91598/), which told me nothing. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a C700 manual that should be helpful.

http://www.jollinger.com/photo/cam-coll/manuals/enlargers/omega/C-700%20Condenser%20and%20Dichro.pdf

Comment: So in your opinion, it actually was not the best possible answer?  :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to turn on enlarger with out activating the switch that controls the bulb (lamp). There are usually two power cords, one is for the fans and or height adjustment motor ( *if it has one* ) and a separate cord for powering and activating the lamp.

You use an enlarger **timer** connected to the enlarger, The bulb receives its power from the timer/switch.

Once you have powered on the enlarger  you then set the timer and pushed the start button? This would activate the bulb for given amount of time you have set on the timer. 
If you do not have a timer your can find the power cord that activates the lamp and plug it directly into an outlet **briefly** to test. ( *some have proprietary plug ends that only fit the timer*)

There are very basic timers and very complex timers. A more complex one is handy and convenient (*programmable*) but not necessary.  You can print with a hand switch and stop watch, wrist watch, wall clock or just count in your head. A timer gives you precision and repeatable control.

As far as changing the bulb, It depends on which head you have on your chassis.

The instructions are in the **basic** instruction manual that waynef referenced and not to hard to figure out with a little exploration.

> The important thing to remember is use a cloth to handle the bulb.